# Itertools group by functionality

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to group by on dict key

```
>>> x
[{'a': 10, 'b': 90}, {'a': 20}, {'a': 30}, {'a': 10}]
>>> [(name, list(group)) for name, group in groupby(x, lambda p:p['a'])]
[(10, [{'a': 10, 'b': 90}]), (20, [{'a': 20}]), (30, [{'a': 30}]), (10, [{'a': 10}])]
```

This must group on key 10 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[docs say](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> `itertools.groupby`:
>   It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes (which is why it is usually **necessary to have sorted the data using the same key function**). That behavior differs from SQL’s GROUP BY which aggregates common elements regardless of their input order.

Comment: >>> x.sort(key=lambda x:x['a'])

>>> [(name, list(group)) for name, group in groupby(x, lambda p:p['a'])]
[(10, [{'a': 10, 'b': 90}, {'a': 10}]), (20, [{'a': 20}]), (30, [{'a': 30}])]

This code solve my problem thx for your support :)